# increment a number and attaching it to function

Tags: javascript

I have a number that acts as a counter stored in a certain database. Every time the page runs the counter increments by 1. I don't have a problem retrieving that number but what I want is to attach that number to a certain name and force a new function.

For example,

`newGame0();`
`newGame1();`
`newGame2();`

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to achieve.. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a clean game each time? But you also want it persisted across page reloads? You could potentially create a game class, and create a new instance of it each time, pushing it to an array, so it wouldn't be `newGame0()`, but could potentially be `var games = []; games.push(new Game()); games[0]()`, but persistence across reloads is a little harder. You could serialize the data using `JSON.stringify`, and save it in localStorage, but stringify doesn't play nicely with functions, so you'd have to write your own `toJson` function. But you need specifics here.

Answer (score 2):

You can define functions `newGame0`, `newGame1`, `newGame2` as properties of an object, use bracket notation to reference property concatenating `counter` `"newGame" + counter`, call function

```js
var counter = 0;

var obj = {
  newGame0: function() {
    console.log(counter)
  },
  newGame1: function() {
    console.log(counter)
  },
  newGame2: function() {
    console.log(counter)
  }

}

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (counter < 3) {
    // call `newGame0`, `newGame1`, `newGame2`
    obj["newGame" + counter](); 
    ++counter;
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
}, 1500)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
self['newGame' + counter] = function()
{
};
```

or

```
self['newGame' + counter] = existingFunctionName;
```

Consider to write a game object with methods in its prototype and hold a set of games in an array instead of messing the global namespace.